# Primefaces p:autocomplete dropdown does not go outside p:dialog

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with the Primefaces 5.2 `p:autocomplete` inside `p:dialog`. The thing is when a user is typing text inside the box, a dropdown shows up inside the dialog within the scroll (see the picture), but I want to dropdown displayed outside the dialog.

[image]

Since the dialog is located above another dialog, I had to use `appendTo="@this"`. This is my code:

```
<p:dialog id="someid" widgetVar="someid-dialog" modal="true">
    <h:form id="someid-form">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                <p:autoComplete appendTo="@this" id="someid-auto" var="pr"
                                value="#{someBean.product}" itemValue="#{pr}" 
                                itemLabel="#{pr.name}#" label="Product"                                      
                                completeMethod="#{someBean.filteredProducts}"
                                converter="productConverter">                            
                </p:autoComplete>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Since the problem is obvious on the client side, I didn't paste my backend code. Putting the form outside the dialog not helped. I had the same problem with `p:selectOneMenu`. I hope somebody has a solution.

Comment: This is excatly as you tell it to behave. It is because you have used the `appendTo="@this"`. Normally the 'popup/out` part is appended to the body of the html and then it works (effectively shown outside the dialog). But then it will not scroll with the content of the dialog if you scroll that (looks detached from the input). You could experiment with using css overflow, but that would introduce other problems as well. This is btw not a PrimeFaces specific problem. Many other frameworks have this problem as well. It's partly due to how browsers/css works.

Comment: You could experiment not using appendTo and add some javascript that 'onscroll' moves the popup part to.

Comment: Kukeltje, thank you for your suggestions! I already played with not using appendTo and css (overflow), but with no success. Hm, It's interesting that it isn't a PrimeFaces specific problem, as you claim, because (for example) the `h:selectOneMenu` works fine, but I need search function which is provided by the `p:selectOneMenu` or `p:autocomplete`. Best regards.

Comment: The `h:*` components render native html. That has no problem. Many other frameworks that use non-native html components instead to create a custom ones have this problem

Comment: hoping you tried `appendTo="@body"` if not please try once and however if it didn't worked add `z index` in `panelStyle` of `autocomplete` make sure you handled `z index` of dialogue also issue is with the `z-index`

Comment: Already tried `appendTo="@body"` and `z-index`, but no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove appendTo="@this" property. you don't want to append the drop down to the dialog.